# TypeError('expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputMediaPhoto') in telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

```
with open(yea_fol, 'rb') as photo:
    media = types.InputMediaPhoto(photo, caption = good)
    bot.edit_message_media(media = open(media, 'rb'), chat_id = call.message.chat.id, message_id = call.message.message_id, reply_markup = vse)
```

Все равно ошибка:

```
TypeError('expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not InputMediaPhoto')
```

Вот текст: `yea_fol = ('C:/Users/gdf/Desktop/my_CODE/bot_for_segun/img/yea.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

А если убрать `open(...)`? Просто подставь media

```
bot.edit_message_media(media=media, ...)
```